# Web Part not saving content

Tags: web-part, modal-dialog, content, viewstate

I developed a Web Part that shows a Modal dialog. An iframe is returned from that dialog and with javascript, pasted into a div on the web part. This is rendered and everything works fine but it does not save the content, after refreshing or even clicking ok + apply.

How can I save the content on the web part page?

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating html in the rendered page does nothing to save content.  The content must be saved either as a web part property (via postback) or as a field in the underlying page (in the case of a Publishing page).  In either case, you will need to post the revised data back to the server in some form.

You would need to elaborate on what exactly you are doing here as the actual answer could be complex.  Also, remember that any actions that take place in an IFrame are not part of the parent page and thus are not reflected in any logic in the parent page.